# Purposely render Adobe files unusable after a specific date

Tags: javascript, powershell, adobe, patch, corrupt

I'm looking for options which would help me render a couple of adobe files ( .indd and .pdf ) that I **will send to someone** unusable after a predetermined date. By unusable, I mean something along the lines of corrupt or expired - something that will not allow the user to view neither the text or the images from the files.

Please let me know if you need more information about this.
So far, I've came across powershell and cron jobs, but both are over my head, and unfortunately, time is not on my side at the moment.

I appreciate you taking the time to read this.
Kind regards.
P.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively sure this cannot be done in general: a PDF file can always be opened by other PDF reader applications. These tools (unlike Adobe Creative Cloud apps) typically will not check if the time of the computer is correct. So your receiver could set the clock of your computer back in time (relatively easy operation) and then open the file with the non-Adobe tool...

EDIT:
That being said this answer on [answers.acrobatusers.com](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/how-create-destruct-pdf-q56856.aspx) suggests that by using Javascript (see the code on the referred page) or a tool called LiveCycle Rights Management server you would probably be able to restrict access to the document when the receiver uses the standard Arcobat tools.

Answer (score 0):

Using the JavaScript API (download the Acrobat SDK [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html)) you can close a document on demand. If you wanted to wrap the document close call around an if statement that, checks a date for example, you could schedule this "de-activation".

This, much like PDF password protection, remains a deterrent that can still be easily disabled by a technical user.

If you are looking for document security like encryption and remote deactivation, [LiveCycle Rights Management](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/livecycle/modules.displayTab3.html#a), now known as AEM Document Security is what you are looking for.